# Как в React принудительно вызвать перересовку всего дерева полностью

Tags: reactjs, mobx

У меня есть событие Login и Logout, мне на них надо полностью перерисовать всю страницу React. Не могу понять как это сделать.

Почему мне это нужно? У меня почти все страницы сайта зависят от пользователя и его прав. И при login и logout мне нужно почти на любой (всех) странице сайта и в любом компоненте заново получить данные с сервера. Так как событие login и logout очень редкие, то что будут где-то вызваны лишние функции перерисовки меня не беспокоит.

Да, если это поможет, я использую MobX для отслеживания переменных. И использую react-router для навигации.

Что я уже попробовал:

```
 var path = CurrentLocationStore.History.location.pathname;
 CurrentLocationStore.History.replace(path);
```

перерисовка не происходит

вот такой хак, по идее должен работать, но почему-то он в 50% срабатывает, а в 50% ничего не перерисоввывает.

```
 var path = CurrentLocationStore.History.location.pathname;
 CurrentLocationStore.History.replace("/");
 CurrentLocationStore.History.replace(path);
```

`CurrentLocationStore.History` это текущая история из `react-router`

Comment: Оказывается это целая задача на react и react-router, вот тут гиганское обсуждение и есть решения - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1982

Comment: что-то как-то коммент не связан с названием вопроса..

Comment: убрать app через state, и отрендерить заного через useEffect? вроде норм вариант, нет?

Answer (score 0):

Из [этого](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1982) обсуждения выяснилось что нормального решения из коробки нет, предложено много хаков для решения этой задачи.

```
var loc = CurrentLocationStore.History.location;
CurrentLocationStore.History.replace("/loading"); // пустая страница
window.setTimeout(function () {
   CurrentLocationStore.History.push(loc);
   });
```

Такое решение-хак у меня работает.